# ctx.drawImage not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a game. The following should draw me a picture of c.png (a coin) but it doesnt work.

There is a example on following link:
http://jonirautiainen.net/html5peli/testi.html

```
<div id="game"></div><script>
var canvasWidth = window.innerWidth - 20;
var canvasHeight = window.innerHeight - 100;
var game = document.getElementById("game");
game.innerHTML = '<canvas id="canvas" width="' + canvasWidth + '"height="' + canvasHeight + '"style="border:solid black 1px"></canvas>';

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var cimg = new Image();
//coin
cimg.src = "c.png";
var time = 0;
var delay = 0;
var coin = {
        srcX: 0,
        srcY: 0,
        w: 90,
        h: 89,
        dw: 40,
        dw: 40,
        x: Math.floor(Math.random() * canvasWidth),
        y: Math.floor(Math.random() * canvasHeight) 
}
ctx.drawImage(cimg, coin.srcX, coin.srcY, coin.w, coin.h, coin.x, coin.y, coin.dw, coin.dh);



</script>
```

Any ideas? It doesnt give me any errors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've typed `dw` twice here:

```
var coin = {
        srcX: 0,
        srcY: 0,
        w: 90,
        h: 89,
        dw: 40,
        dw: 40,
        x: Math.floor(Math.random() * canvasWidth),
        y: Math.floor(Math.random() * canvasHeight) 
};
```

The second one should be `dh: 40` instead. =)

Comment: OMG are you serious :) been trying to find out whats wrong for 3 hours... Thanks so much.

Comment: @JoniJuhaniRautiainen: Nicely done :) I kept looking at it for a long time too, then I added [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode) and it showed up.